# Not a Bom character in PHP but a - messing up my styles

Tags: php

I Have just updated the question to a much more basic version: You can view the source code at http://www.3d-casino-game.com/da/sitemap.asp in notepad to see what I am talking about:

In notepad the `<title>` tag is in a different font size as all the rest of the characters. The problem that I am having is that there is a - character included in the page each time that I use a php include:

Here is a basic page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/head.php');?>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and the included page is exactly like this:

```
<title>3D Casino Games</title>
<link href="http://www.3d-casino-game.com/css/3d-casino-game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why is the special character there?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that whitespace after the `?>` *will* print to the page. In PHP, you can get away with not having the `?>` closing your file, and PHP will accept it. Try removing that from your includes, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have removed all the spaces behind the ?> no luck, even the spaces before it...

Comment: Check if your file encodings are Unix UTF-8, and not something like Windows ASCII...

Comment: I have finally found the error, the pages were indeed in BOM although W3C did not pick it up!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check /includes/javascript.php ?
It probably has a new line before the `<?php` tag or inside it ( as output ).

Try to include the javascript file in another clean file and check if the new line is still present.

Comment: I have disabled the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as your javascript.php not outputting anything. This could be due to an error in the javascript.php file and you have display_errors off. Check the PHP error log if error_logging is on.

Comment: I have temporary disabled the javascript.php file and still have the error